# How safe is it to run an un unpatched, internet-exposed OpenSSH service?

Tags: attacks, ssh, vulnerability, openssh

There have recently been several reported security [issues](https://www.openssh.com/security.html) with OpenSSH (Terrapin, double-frees, remote execution, X11 forwarding vulnerabilities..). How safe is it for a server to expose OpenSSH (using public key authentication) to the internet?

For example, if the server were significantly (e.g. 5-10 years) behind on patches, how feasible would it be for attackers to break into the server without the private key?

Comment: SSH is a protocol. OpenSSH is a service. You can't compare the two things. That page you link also lists the fixes to all those problems with OpenSSH. So, the lesson is: update your internet-facing services.

Comment: Once you refine the question to problems with the ***service*** your search queries get a lot more fruitful: https://jfrog.com/blog/openssh-pre-auth-double-free-cve-2023-25136-writeup-and-proof-of-concept/

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSH is extremely popular and frequently exposed remotely. Exploiting it provides a fairly high degree of access to the machine. My experience with internet facing SSH is that it experiences a **lot** of drive by attack traffic. In other words, your (5-10 year old) SSH server will be tested. Older vulnerabilities are much easier to get exploits for as well since disclosure delays are already well expired.

In the linked document in your question about known vulnerabilities, or by searching CVE databases for OpenSSH, there are ample known exploits. Disabling certain authentication mechanisms or requiring keys for authentication might help a little, but the reality is that any pre-authentication or authentication bypass style exploit is going to be a legitimate hazard.

To manage a machine with this sort of disability a much better strategy would be to hide it behind an up to date firewall with some sort of VPN or tunnel to provide access. At least an IP based firewall rule. Because yes, the ancient SSHD is going to get hacked.